# Drupal 7 view - incorrect number of items per page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Inherited a Drupal 7 site with a view.

The Page display is configured to have a pager, with 5 items per page. However, it will only display 2 items per page.

The *preview* has 5 items. The actual page as viewed does not.

I tried giving the pager an ID (based on the help text for the Pager ID field) but it didn't change anything.

I don't have server access, just Drupal admin access (yeah, I know) so I can't check for PHP errors and I can't inspect the code. On the Drupal side, though, it looks fairly straightforward. Yet each page has two items, not five.

Googling is not shedding light on this.

Must be missing something - what should I be checking here?

Comment: Too many things can go wrong, clear the caches, memcached, check for views alter query/pre_view/pre_render/post_render, check node permissions, etc. Check if the items are in the source code. Add new display page and see it on different URL. If you've Devel enabled, go to: `/devel/php`, you can execute whatever you want without server access. Finally you've to debug it, download the db & code and try xdebug.

Comment: Are you looking at view preview and actual view as same logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing a disconnect between the preview of a Drupal 7 view and the actual page, a likely culprit is that your page has a parameter that you're not setting in the preview. Parameters can come from many sources - the URL, the currently logged-in user, and so on. Check the Contextual Filters section of the view, and click on any existing contextual filters to see how they are set up. You can feed contextual filters to the preview using the "Preview with contextual filters" text box next to the Preview button.